# How to insert an image (selection) in an Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, imageview, android-alertdialog

I'm making an app that allows the user to create **several entries** in a *ListView*.
I have a `MainActivity` with a floating button that starts an *AlertDialog* such as this one:

[image: The AlertDialog currently displayed]

As you can see from the following ListView, at the moment each entry has the same icon (the green android logo).

[image: ListView in the MainActivity]

I would like to make the **user select an icon among a set of icons I created on purpose before**. The idea is to put a little image (the default one) next to the `Insert package name here` text, on the left. Once the user clicks on the picture he gets displayed a list with all (let's say 9) icons available.

How can I do it? I hope I explained myself well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setIcon(Drawable icon)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) or [`setIcon(int iconId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setIcon(int)).

If you want more customization, you can create a class extends DialogFragment and create a custom layout for your AlertDialog.

Comment: `setIcon()` puts an image next to the title of the *AlertDialog*. I want that picture to be displayed next to the other line of text! I think I'll have to create a custom layout as you say... but what about the multiple selection of icons? Any idea? Thanks for support

Comment: You can set your icons where you set your texts in your adapter.